# Replacing a light switch with a smart switch

Tags: electrical, lighting, uk, smart-switch

I'm trying to replace my existing light switch (in my new build home in the UK) with a Innens smart WiFi switch (https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07RK5F8HC/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_jNHbEbVEDEEF6 ). My existing wiring seems to be different from what I can read in the smart switch instructions or what others seem to have. I have 2 brown wires going into "COM", 1 brown wire into "1 WAY" and 3 blue wires going into "LOOP". What's the correct way to connect the smart switch to this type of wiring setup? [image]

Comment: Can you post a photo looking into the back of the box please?

Comment: Classic fake, unsafe product, we see this all the time.  CE mark only, sold only through banggood and Amazon Marketplace (note third party seller), no sign of any BSI listing, nor TUV, CSA, ETL, UL nor any other competent testing lab.  CE is meaningless when imported from outside the EU , and is faked on anything sold direct from China, as is the case here. (The detour via the Amazon Warehouse means nothing). This thing is a firestarter. Send it back!